# count multiple values of a row in sql

Tags: sql

i have a table with following data set

```
ID      ReportID    RecIDs

7083    52682      47407,47505,33648,47412,
4419    52749      47412,47218,36636,47866,47669,47505,47259,
7496    52883      47488,
6547    52936      47345,47236,47407,33648,47512,47412,47254,47274,36636,
6225    53066      47412,36636,47236,47254,47367,33648,
2733    53067      47218,47221,47236,33648,47866,36636,33595,39485,
6923    53084      37061,47412,47407,47376,47274,47505,47651,47820,
```

I want to write a query which will give me the count of all the comma seperated entries in RedIDs column. 
Like what will be the count of the value of RecIDs for row id  6923

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? But you shouldn't be storing comma separated values in the first place. You should fix your data model, then your query becomes _very_ simple.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `REPLACE`:

```
SELECT ID, ReportID, RecIDs,
       LEN(RecIDs) - LEN(REPLACE(RecIDs, ',', '')) AS cnt
FROM mytable
WHERE ID = 6923
```

This counts the number of `','` present in `RecIDs` column. This should be equivalent to the number of numbers in it.

Comment: Just a note, LEN is product specific, and no dbms is specified.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(len(RecIDs) - len(replace(RecIDs, ',', '')) +1) 
    AS RedIDs
FROM DBTABLE
```

Comment: Just a note, LEN is product specific, and no dbms is specified.

Comment: This question is having sql tag.

Comment: SQL is a language, not a product. And LEN is not included in the ANSI SQL standard...